# Hiding Specific URL Variable After Load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a small database that books candidates for events and I'm passing messages using `GET` variables named 'message'

An example to run a jQuery popup window for a confirmation would be:

```
www.domain.com/load_page.php?id=1&message=BookingCreated
```

This would then trigger a popup message. I'm using JQuery Confirm:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("message=BookingCreated") > -1) {
            $.alert({theme: 'custom', title: 'Booking Confirmed',content: 'Confirmation has been sent to both you and the candidate.',});  
        }
```

However I would like to hide the 'message' variable after the page is loaded but I only know how to hide all variables using:

```
if(typeof window.history.pushState == 'function') {
    window.history.pushState({}, "Hide", '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>');
}
```

This would give me `www.domain.com/load_page.php`, however I would like to only hide anything that contains 'message' as if the user refreshed the page it would cause the page to load incorrectly.

Can this be done or should I be looking at another method to pass responses?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can just switch to using `post`...

Comment: if its a redirect to a confirmation page _after_ an update to the db, you could pass the message to the confirmation page via a _session_ var rather than get (and make sure to clear it on the receiving page). ... _Except you're doing your redirect in Javascript rather than from PHP....so you can't._

Answer (score 0):

This might work. If you have a url like: http://foo.bar?meow=stuff&message=heyo you should end up with http://foo.bar/?meow=stuff

If you start off with http://foo.bar, you end up with http://foo.bar/? but that shouldn't hurt anything.

```js
let remove = str => '?' + location.search.substring(1).split('&').filter( q => q.indexOf(str)).join('&');
history.pushState(null, 'hide', remove('message'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look a [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)

Parse the URI then remove the parameters via the `.removeSearch` function

```
URI("www.domain.com/load_page.php?id=1&message=BookingCreated")
    .removeSearch("message")
    .toString()
        // -> "www.domain.com/load_page.php?id=1"
```

But as mentioned in the comments. There might be a better way to handle this. Either with POST or session variables. You may want to ask another question outlining the user workflow and what you're trying to achieve.